# axis work correctly but button doesn't in Android Build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm Building a VR mobile game and I control this Game by PS3 controller, The Controller work very well in Unity editor with all buttons and axis. And when I connect the controller with android phone all the button works and axis too. **The Problem that's when I build the Game in Android only axis work buttons doesn't.**
Although I change the Input Manager settings many times it's also did nothing. And did several things like:

1. This line of code get the axis value:

   ```
   float steering = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
   ```
2. So I tried to get value from button and make virtual button named
   "joystickButton2" like this:

   ```
   bool speed = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("joystickButton2");
   ```

   it doesn't work too.
3. I replace the `CrossPlatformInputManager` class with regular `Input`
   class and it similar to the `CrossPlatformInputManager` class.

   ```
   bool speed = Input.GetButton("joystickButton2");
   ```
4. I tried to get the key it-self by `GetKey` function like:

   ```
       bool speed = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.joystickbutton2);
   ```

   Nothing happened too. I tried many things and several things but still only axis work and buttons didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the Solution. 
The problem was the Android reads the inputs from PS3 controller in weired way, Like the X button was the `joystickButton14` so I've made a simple loop for all buttons and display the result on the game itself on Android and when I connect the Controller so I know exactly what the number of `joystickButton`.

```
public Text ButtonNumber;
void Update (){
  for (int i = 0 ; i =< 100 ; i++ ){
    string JoyStick = "joystickButton"+ i.ToString();
    if (input.GetKey(KeyCode.JoyStick)){
      ButtonNubmber.text = i.ToString();
}}}
```

I hope that's help someone.